# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**It shots error in id:doc.id and post : doc.data()**
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("posts").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          setPost(
            snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
              id: doc.id,
              post: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        });
      }, []);
 
      return (
    
          {post.map(({ id, post }) => (
            <Post
              key={id}
              username={post.username}
              caption={post.caption}
              imageURL={post.imageURL}
            />
          ))}
      );
```

Comment: this error likely occurs in your render function. Probably want to show your render codes, and snapshot.docs sample so we know what's being rendered.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet? If yes, could you share it?

Answer (score 9):

### This error occurs when a javascript object has been included inside some jsx tags.

It is that simple.

Consider the following example:

```js
// A simple javascript object (also a dictionary) containing three keys
const someObject = {
  name: 'Simple Javascript object',
  id: 123,
  someFunction: function() {
    return <p>This function returned more jsx!</p>;
  }
}

const SimpleFunctionComponent = () => <h2>{someObject}</h2>;
```

> *It is important to note that `<h2>{someObject}</h2>` here is not html, it is jsx. React will parse it and create the corresponding elements in the dom using javascript. The contents between/inside two corresponding component tags (like `<h2>` and `</h2>` here) are considered the child or children of the component.*

In this example, if I try and render `<SimpleFunctionComponent />` I will get the error

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, id, someFunction}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

`someObject` is not a valid React child. To my knowledge only `string`, `int` and more jsx are. `someObject` is not any of these things.

If I modify `SimpleFunctionComponent` slightly it will work.

```js
const SimpleFunctionComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>STRING: {someObject.name}</h2>
    <p>INT: {someObject.id}</p>
    <p>JSX: {someObject.someFunction()}</p>
  </div>
);
```

### The only real bit of information here to help debug this sort of problem is the error message will provide you with the keys inside of the object causing the error.

In the OP's code the error is coming from this

```js
<Post 
    key={id} 
    username={post.username} 
    caption={post.caption} 
    imageURL={post.imageURL} 
/>;
```

Note: The code above is completely valid but the error will come from the rendering of the `Post` component where any of these attributes are used as a React child.

> e.g.
>
> ```js
> // If Post was a functional component
> const Post = (props) => {
>    return (
>        <div>
>            <h1>{props.username}</h1>
>            <p>{props.caption}</p>
>            <img src={props.imageURL} alt="post image"/>
>        </div>
>    )
> }
> ```

Without knowing what the structure of `post.id` or `post.post` are all we can deduce is that any one of `id`, `post.username`, `post.caption`, and `post.imageURL` is actually an object with the key username inside.

> `(found: object with keys {username})`.

Lets assume it is `post.username`, the OP thought the structure of `post` was

```js
const post = {
    id: 'some id',
    post: {
        username: 'some username',
        caption: 'some caption',
        imageURL: 'some image url'
    }
}
```

when it was actually

```js
const post = {
    id: 'some id',
    post: {
        username: {
            username: 'some username'
        },
        caption: 'some caption',
        imageURL: 'some image url'
    }
}
```

and would need to put `username={post.username.username}` instead.
This would be the same respectively for `id`, `post.caption`, and `post.imageURL` if they were actually the object causing the error.

Here is a [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/object-is-not-a-valid-react-child-qb8ft?file=/src/App.js) of the example I provided and one replicating the situation the OP had.